# help in joomla reset password

Tags: joomla, reset

i have problem in joomla password reset

i can't access to my admin panel and

i want to reset it from here

http://www.jotapege.es/index.php?option=com_user&view=reset

but there is no form to reset

i'm using joomla 1.0

tried to change password from phpmyadmin   not work

if you can help me and tell me

how to reset it

how can i active the password reset form  if it in database

thank you

Answer (score 0):

First empty the usertable from phpmyadmin and 
Run this query from phpmyadmin :

```
INSERT INTO `jos_users` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `usertype`, `block`, `sendEmail`, `gid`, `registerDate`, `lastvisitDate`, `activation`, `params`) VALUES
(62, 'Administrator', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', '795bd3a70e6092b3b2ef4cf693791a19:hxBIPX2KGcaNPQXtfQ78MlSjX8eqaK8P', 'Super Administrator', 0, 1, 25, '2011-01-02 08:29:32', '2011-05-18 08:09:32', '', '')
```

Then login with :
user: `admin`
pass: `admin`

Comment: i did it before many times and did it as you told me but with the same error  can't access the administrator page  can you please tell me how to active password reset from database or php files ??????